# Чем обусловлено столь странное поведение при сложении list и tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuple

Заметили такую странную штуку:

```
>>> a = [3]
>>> a += (1,2)
>>> print(a)
[3, 1, 2]
>>> (1,2) + [3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple
>>> [3] + (1,2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list
```

Может ли кто-то объяснить почему так странно работает их сложение? -_-

Comment: это описано в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range), или поищите русский перевод

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
type(a)
<class 'list'>
```

Тут тип list

```
a += (4, 5)
type(a)
<class 'list'>
```

Логично предположить, что если переменная была типа list, то она и останется list.

А вот какой результат был бы при сложении `[1, 2] + (3, 4)`? Tuple или list? А если наоборот сложить сначала кортеж, а потом список? Чтоб не морочить программистам головы разработчики python решили просто запретить складывать их напрямую и все.